# ChromeDriver and SpecRun Issue: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Tags: multithreading, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, specflow, specrun

When running Selenium automated tests in C# through SpecRunner using ChromeDriver (especially when running in multiple threads), we keep intermittently seeing this exception:

Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

It happens randomly on about 20% of tests every run and gets worse as more threads are added.

We are really at wit's end, so any ideas/suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Could you add a stack trace of the exception? How do you instantiate the ChromeDriver?

Answer (score 0):

From class ChromeOptions, try comment the argument --remote-debugging-port
It works for me.

For example:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions
{
    AcceptInsecureCertificates = true        
};
//chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=922");
```

Maybe you are using chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=922");

"That line" is currently deprecated.

Sorry for late

Comment: could you elaborate on this one? What you mean with "try comment the argument"? I get this error but I do no have this argument to "comment out" if that is what you mean?

Comment: chromeOptions.AddArgument("--remote-debugging-port=X");